# Help with a custom rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, single

The following is a snippet from single.php

```
                                    </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php 
                                    if($_GET['m'] != "gallery") {
                                            the_content();
                                    else {
                                            echo do_shortcode('[gallery link="file"]');
                                    }
                            ?>      

                                    <?php wp_link_pages(); ?>

                                    <div class='clear'></div>
```

So if I append ?m=gallery to the URL it will convert single.php into a gallery, else it will show the normal content. I was wondering how I could rewrite ?m=gallery to just /gallery. I am using `/%category%/%postname%/` as a custom permalink structure. I would like `/%category%/%postname%/%m%` where %m% is $_GET['m']. My htaccess has the following:

```
    RewriteEngine On


    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to use the WordPress rewrite API. No .htaccess required.

First, hook into `init` and add a rewrite endpoint to your permalinks.  This tells WordPress that whens some visits `/category/post-slug/gallery` match the new endpoint rewrite.  it also takes care of adding the query variable for you so you don't have to do that.

```
<?php
add_action( 'init', 'wpse27638_add_rewrite' );
function wpse27638_add_rewrite()
{
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'gallery', EP_PERMALINK );    
}
```

Next up we have to hack the endpoint system a bit because it doesn't automatically work whens someone visits `some-permalink/some-endpoint`: your new query variable (`gallery`) would only contain a value when someone visits `category/permalink/gallery/something`.  No good.  So we hook into `request`.  If our new `gallery` query variable is set, we'll just make it so the value is always set to true.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse27638_request' );
function wpse27638_request( $vars )
{
    if( isset( $vars['gallery'] ) ) $vars['gallery'] = true;
    return $vars;   
}
```

Next up, we need to hook into `the_content`.  If our new query var is set, we'll return a gallery shortcode in place of the content.  Otherwise, we'll just return the content. You can remove your `if else` statement from `single.php` and just put in `the_content` in its place.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse27638_content_filter' );
function wpse27638_content_filter( $content )
{   
    if( ! is_singular() ) return $content;
    if( get_query_var( 'gallery' ) )
    {
        return '[gallery link="file"]'; 
    }
    else
    {
        return $content;        
    }
}
```

Only one finishing touch on our plugin.  Add the new endpoint and flush the rewrite rules on activation.  And flush the rewrite rules again on deactivation.

```
<?php
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse27638_activation' );
function wpse27638_activation()
{
    wpse27638_add_rewrite();
    flush_rewrite_rules();  
}

register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'wpse27638_deactivation' );
function wpse27638_deactivation()
{
    flush_rewrite_rules();
}
```

Here's the only thing as a plugin (ready to use): https://gist.github.com/1191865

Comment: Thank you so much! How does this scale? Does it add many more queries?

Comment: Not sure.  You're going to have to ask someone more skilled in the ways of server stuff/optimization than I.